# then function not returning values Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I'm doing something with Chart.js. I am using this function ($scope.getAreas) to get the information to build the charts. When I print the variables ($scope.AreasInteres) outside the "then" function it returns "undefined".

```
var app = angular.module('App', ["chart.js"]);

app.controller('chartsCtrl', function($http, $scope) {
   var vt = this;
   vt.chartPieLabels = ["Revistas", "Libros", "Internet", "Otros"];
   vt.chartPieCharts = [152, 51, 68, 210];
   vt.chartPieOptions = {
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      responsive: true
   };
   vt.chartPieColours =['#494750', '#999999', '#cc3321', '#2fb467'];

   $scope.AreasInteres;

   $scope.getAreas = function(){
      $http({
          url: 'contarAreasInteres/',
          method: 'GET'
      }).then(function (response) {
          $scope.AreasInteres = response.data;
          console.log($scope.AreasInteres);
      }); 
      console.log($scope.AreasInteres);
   };

   $scope.getAreas();

});
```

I've been using the same way to get things from REST in the same project and I didn't have problems.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `.then` function returns a promise, meaning that it waits for async tasks to be finished and executes it's callback function when it's done. It still continues to execute further code down the road.

Angulars `$http` service returns a promise which gets resolved when the async call to `contarAreasInteres` is done or fails due to an error. So it makes sense that outside of `.then` your `console.log` prints `undefined` because there was yet no data received.

[Here](https://www.promisejs.org/) is an explanation why promises are important and how they work.